# Testing function with BOOST.Test

Tags: c++, testing, boost

I have a fnc:

```
template<class T, T constraint>
inline void CheckSize(const T& value)
{
 if (value < constraint)
 {
  throw BadSize_ex(value);
 }
}
```

but I cannot test it with Boost. What I'm doing is this ():

```
BOOST_REQUIRE_THROW(CheckSize<int,2>(1),std::BadSize_ex);
```

Where is the problem?
but I'm getting lots of miningless errors of type ',' missing before ';'.

**Errors** (Some of them but all of them are from this ball park)
Error 5 error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'
Error 6 error C2143: syntax error : missing '>' before '{'
Error 7 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
Error 8 error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
Error 45 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
Error 46 error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found

Comment: Could you post your error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the comma between template parameters. Try with additional paranthesis:

```
BOOST_REQUIRE_THROW( (CheckSize<int,2>(1)),std::BadSize_ex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BOOST_PP_COMMA() in place of , if you want to pass commas within parameters instead of to delimit parameters. This is basically because the preprocessor can't recognize template parameter delimiting over macro parameter delimiting.